# Delete DataGoogle Fit API

Tags: google-fit

I am Using Google Fit For Recording Step . Dont Clear Data Google Fit Day. 2 Button in Application . number one Start Record Step ,number two for Stop Record

My Code For Start Recoud

```
Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        });
        //
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        });
        //
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Code For Delete Data Not Working

```
public void ClearHistory(){
        Log.i(TAG, "Deleting today's step count data");

        // [START delete_dataset]
        // Set a start and end time for our data, using a start time of 1 day before this moment.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -20);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        //  Create a delete request object, providing a data type and a time interval
        DataDeleteRequest request = new DataDeleteRequest.Builder()
                .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .build();

        // Invoke the History API with the Google API client object and delete request, and then
        // specify a callback that will check the result.
        Fitness.HistoryApi.deleteData(mClient, request)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {

                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully deleted today's step count data");
                            Toast.makeText(p_context,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(p_context,status.getStatus().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // The deletion will fail if the requesting app tries to delete data
                            // that it did not insert.
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to delete today's step count data");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

For Get Data

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(p_context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(p_context))
                .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<DataSet>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DataSet dataSet) {
                                long total =
                                        dataSet.isEmpty()
                                                ? 0
                                                : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();

                                //String Calley = dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).toString();
                                /*
                                long distance =
                                        dataSet.isEmpty()
                                                ? ""
                                                : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE.getFormat());
                                               */
                                //
                                Log.i("countstep", "Total steps: " + total);
                                //CalleryStart = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Calley));
                                //distancestart = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(distance));
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString( total),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w("errorcountstep", "There was a problem getting the step count.", e);
                            }
                        });
```

this Codes for Google Fit Api not Working I am Using Google Fit Version  16.0.1 dont word. Get Data SuccessFully Work And record Step... . no Working Delete History. I am Using Google Fit API Documention